# Selenium test slow

Tags: javascript, performance, selenium, html

I have a web page which has a table.
There is a script that add rows to the table, and whenever a row being added some calculation being applied.
I wrote a selenium test, that add 1000 rows.
The test start fast, and the more rows being added the more the test become slower.
the table is huge and has around 40 TD, and each one has one input item.
all the javascript code written in jquery.

I tried to speed up the code, and even drop some calculation, with no effect of the performance at all.
is there a way to know if the slow down from the code, or from Selenium test?
How can i profile?
 I am trying to use firebug profiler, but Selenium disables firebug when running.

Comment: For Selenium, you can add in the Firebug xpi file to the profile that Selenium creates. For example, in the ruby version of the Selenium WebDriver library (Selenium 2), code for adding the XPI can be found in the "Adding an extension" section here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings. Would that give you what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you adding a row one at a time or all at once? Try collecting all of the data and then adding rows and see if that speeds anything up.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the Chrome profiler. You can write a simple test case in Javascript that does a similar operation to your Selenium test (add 1000 rows, etc), and profile it with the Chrome dev tools. I find they are very handy for tracking down slowdowns and memory leaks.